# Escaping a symbol in jq expression in a shell script

Tags: linux, shell, jq

I have two variables `var1` and `var2` exported in my shell.

```
var1=root 
var2=webserver
```

I want a jq query which can replace a JSON key with the given value in the JSON file. something like that,

```
jq -r --arg var1 $var1 --arg var2 $var2 '(.[].appId=$var1-$var2)' service.json
```

It is giving error that var1 and var2 can't be subtracted. But i want the variable to be replaced with `$var1-$var2` as a string.

I tried with `"-"`, But it's giving compilation error.

service.json content is following.

```
[ {
      "appId": "Eternal Flame",
      "age": 1000000,
      "secretIdentity": "Unknown",
      "powers": [
        "Immortality",
        "Heat Immunity",
        "Inferno",
        "Teleportation",
        "Interdimensional travel"
      ]
    } ]
```

appId value should be replaced with "root-webserver"

Comment: Any reason you are passing the two values separately, rather than combining them ahead of time? `jq -r --arg newId "$var1-$var2" '(.[].appID=$newID)' service.json`?

Comment: Yeah, There is no specific reason. This solution looks brilliant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `-` tries to do an arithmetic subtraction on the items. I recommend to use [String interpolation](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Stringinterpolation-%5C(foo)). It will automatically cast input to a string:

```
jq -r --arg var1 $var1 --arg var2 $var2 '(.[].appId="\($var1)-\($var2)")' service.json
```